# How is the system equation formulated? [Resource Allocation Problem]

Tags: dynamic-programming, optimal-control

I do not find how the following system equation is formulated. The following example is about the Deterministic Continuous-Time Optimal Control chapter.

---

We are considering a continuous-time dynamic system 
$$\dot{x}(t) = f(x(t),u(t)), \qquad 0\le t\lt T, \tag1\\ x(0) : \text{given,}$$
where $x(t)\in\Bbb{R}^n$ is the state vector at time $t$, $\dot{x}(t)\in\Bbb{R}^n$ is the vector of first order time derivatives of the states at time $t$, $u(t)\in U \subset \Bbb{R}^m$ is the control vector at time $t$, $U$ is the control constraint set, and $T$ is the terminal time.

The system $(1)$ represents the $n$ first order differential equations $$\frac{dx_i(t)}{dt} = f_i(x(t), u(t)), \qquad i=1, \cdots, n.$$

### Example 3.1.2 (Resource Allocation)

A producer with production rate $x(t)$ at time $t$ may allocate a portion $u(t)$ of his/her production rate to reinvestment and $1-u(t)$ to production of a storable good. Thus $x(t)$ evolves according to $$\dot{x}(t)=\gamma u(t)x(t),\tag2$$ where $\gamma\gt0$ is a given constant. The producer wants to maximize the total amount of product stored $$\int_0^T \left(1-u(t)\right)x(t)dt$$ subject to $$ 0\le u(t)\le 1, \qquad \text{for all } t\in [0, T].$$
The initial production rate $x(0)$ is a given positive number.

---

I do not understand where and how the equation $(2)$ is derived from. Please let me understand it. Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: Equation (2) is not derived, it is an example (as the headline suggests) for a dynamical system. So you cannot understand it, it is given (and from the point of view of application it might be reasonable to chose that ode for the production rate, but this would be a question which is more related to modeling...)

Comment: @Alex Hmm... it is just example... Although it gives me a bit doubt on why this example should be introduced here, I got it. Thank you.